# 2Wire USB Network Adapter Not Working With Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

[image: 2Wire image]

I installed Windows 7 on a separate drive, and everything works fine, but I can't get the above network adapter to work properly. It's displayed in Device Manager as a USB device, and I have the driver that makes it function in Vista, but when I run the Driver Wizard and direct it to directory where I have the Vista driver, it almost immediately says "Can't install driver."

Is there any work around to this?

Answer (score 1):

2Wire USB Network Adapter I have came with a QUEST HIGH SPEED QUICK CONNECT 3.6 install disk which it recognized immediately and have had no problems. 
Just do a driver update from the device manager and have it search the disk.

Answer (score 0):

> According to Microsoft, development milestones of Windows 7 fail to play nice with USB network adapters that rely on pre-Windows Vista drivers. The symptoms involve NDIS 5.x USB network adapters not being displayed in the Windows 7 Performance Monitor. NDIS refers to the Network Driver Interface Specification library, which, following the transition from Windows XP to Windows Vista, evolved to version 6.0. Version 5 of NDIS was used by Windows operating systems before Vista.

Comment: Ugh. Is there any fix to it? What would you suggest I do? It says pre-Windows Vista drivers, but I have a driver in Vista for it, and it functions fine in Vista.

Comment: You could try running it in compatibility mode - http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html

Comment: I'll try that. But, the thing is, the way I got it working on Vista was with the .sys driver file and then Updating the driver through Device Manager. Since I don't have a driver installation program, and only the driver file, would this still possibly work?

Comment: Oh, and if you check back here, can you suggest any USB phoneline adapters that are compatible with 64-bit Windows 7, so that I can just go to Staples or Bestbuy or something and buy one if I don't get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible windows 7 does not like the digital signature for your driver.

Try the steps in this link.

http://www.mydigitallife.info/force-load-unsigned-drivers-in-test-mode-easily-in-windows-7-or-vista-with-driver-signature-enforcement-overrider/

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)